# Compile dustjs html templates with grunt, uncompressed for development

Tags: gruntjs, dust.js

Can anyone help me out please, i have a phonegap app and need to compile the html files to dustjs templates. But the compiled version is minified. Can anyone suggest a away to get the un-minified version ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that the rendered output is compressed because dust strips whitespace.

To disable this behavior set `dust.config.whitespace = true` before compiling your templates. Depending on what grunt plugin you use, there may be a whitespace parameter you can set in your grunt config that will pass through to dust.